# Ubuntu increase size

Tags: partitioning, gparted

My pc has one windows and two different ubuntu version. I want to remove old ubuntu version and increase new ubuntu version using old version space without lose my datas in new version. Is it possible?

ubuntu old uses sda8.

ubuntu new version uses sda10.

If I unmount sda8, gparted edition say that "Unmount any logical partitipns having a number higher than 8". If I do it, will I lose my datas under new ubuntu version?

How can I uninstall ubuntu old version? After installation, how can I merge sda8 and sd10 without installation and lose my datas under sda10?

Comment: For anybody to give any recommendations, they'd first have to see a screenshot of gparted view of your sda hard disk. Post it here for us to look at. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gparted is available on all Ubuntu bootable USB's (Live CD).  You should certainly backup all of your data before you do anything.  There is always a chance that something can go wrong.  Adding space that is listed **after** a partition is easy.  Adding space before is a little tricky.

If it is after, delete the partition with GParted, and resize.

It is likely, the old logical partition you want to remove and add space to the new installation is before your current Ubuntu partition.  Deleting that old partition and the reformatting it and using it as a data drive is much safer.
If you leave the deleted partition unformatted, gparted will let you take that other drive and resize over it.  You will get a warning that you are moving a bootable file to a new location.  Cross your fingers and say yes.

You might have to install (on a writable usb), boot-repair.  This will help find the grub files if all goes wrong.  I think I have done this exact same process before and it worked when I removed a Swap partition that was before my ubuntu partition.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
```

Best of luck.
Remember these three things:

1. Data backup
2. USB Bootable Ubuntu and 1 gb of persistence (any flavor/version)
3. Have boot-repair installed just in case something goes wrong.